Error when trying to add BA-DUA in project
This is my first time with BA-DUA, and online there isn't so much to learn about (at least where I searched). I wanted to add this tool for  data-flow testing coverge in my project. I added this in my project pom.xml:

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/br.usp.each.saeg/ba-dua -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>br.usp.each.saeg</groupId>
        <artifactId>ba-dua</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

And it goes perfectly; but when adding this in the poms' module (where are my tests), it tells me that "Dependency br.usp.each.saeg:ba-dua-cli:${ba-dua.version} not found".
    <profile>
      <id>BaDuaCoverage</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>!skipBaDuaCoverage</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <ba-dua.version>0.8.1-SNAPSHOT</ba-dua.version>
        <argLine>-javaagent:target/dependency/ba-dua-agent-rt-${ba-dua.version}-all.jar -Doutput.file=${project.build.directory}/badua.ser</argLine>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>br.usp.each.saeg</groupId>
          <artifactId>ba-dua-cli</artifactId>
          <version>${ba-dua.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>br.usp.each.saeg</groupId>
                      <artifactId>ba-dua-agent-rt</artifactId>
                      <classifier>all</classifier>
                      <version>${ba-dua.version}</version>
                    </artifactItem>
                  </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>br.usp.each.saeg.badua.cli.Report</mainClass>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>-input</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/badua.ser</argument>
                    <argument>-classes</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>
                    <argument>-show-classes</argument>
                    <argument>-show-methods</argument>
                    <argument>-xml</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/badua.xml</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

